# figuring out if a seat is available for a specific itinerary

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

So I've got an interesting problem here that I'd like to find an elegant solution to. In this case, I don't really have any code written as what I'm looking for is more of an algorithm. Once I know how to do it, I should be able to translate into a programming language. So here's the deal:

Suppose you have a train with 3 seats that travels to 6 stations (the numbers can vary here, but if it works for these numbers, it should work for all of them and I think it helps to have actual numbers to better understand the problem).

So we have seat 1, 2 and 3 and stations A, B, C, D, E, F

A person can come in at any station to travel to a station that's further away. There's no loop here so you can't travel F ---> A (It also means that no one's going to be coming in at station F).

Also, and I'm not certain how to phrase this, but seats are not "assigned" so to speak. Basically, if a person wants to go A-->C and seat 1 is available A-->B and seat 2 is available B-->C then we consider there's indeed space for the person to ride (basically a person will just walk in and seat on whatever seat's available).

So now, my problem is that I'd like to know how many seats are available for a given itinerary at any time.

As you can tell, if I have three people going A-->F then I'm full, no one can get in.

However, if I have

```
A-->C
A-->B
A-->E
B-->D
```

Then I have like <s>2 seats</s> 1 seat available if I want to go C-->D or <s>1 seat</s> none available if I want to go B-->D and so on and so forth. As you can tell, things get really complicated really fast so I need an algorithm that would efficiently allow me to calculate this.

Right now, the only solution I could find is this (in pseudo-code):

```
itinerary = x-->y

for stations s going from x to y
    seatsAvailable[s] = 3 - count reservations starting at or before x and ending after x

availableSeats = min(seatsAvailable);
```

Comment: And what is "wrong" with that solution?

Comment: Nothing really, just wanted to know if there was another alternative, that's all

Comment: The only reason I can see to replace your proposed algorithm would be performance. To pick a better alternative you'd need to start by explaining in detail the performance to be improved. For example if the number of free seats at each station is always needed, you could start by storing the number of seats in each element of an array with one element per station. Then process each trip by subtracting 1 from each respective seat count.  0 means out of seats, so no trip. Otoh for huge numbers of stops/trips, a fancy data structure like an interval tree would speed things up.

Comment: The solution depends on the number of stations, seats and trips you expect. What are the maximum numbers you want this to work for?

Comment: @trincot 3 is the most standard number of seats we have (which is why I picked this number) with 5 being the absolute maximum. As for the stations, 6 is on the high end of what we usually see. I have seen more (I did see a trip of 10 stations once), but most of the time what we see are trips ranging between 2-5 stations. So I picked a high-end number figuring it'd be easier to downsize the algorithm than to upscale it

Comment: OK, but for such tiny numbers, you cannot possibly have a performance issue, right? We're talking about milliseconds... Your pseudo code looks fine, although it could use some more detail.

Comment: You write *"1 seat available if I want to go B-->D"*, but I don't see a seat available when that person wants to get on the train at B: you already have 4 trips, and of those, still 3 are ongoing at station B, so there are 3 people already on the train. Can you clarify?

Comment: @trincot You're right, I screwed up my example lol. I'm editing things to correct myself

Answer (score 0):

'my problem is that I'd like to know how many seats are available for a given itinerary at any time.', since your train is only one way I think that time does not have any importance in your problem, if you are using some type of object-oriented programming you can add a variable empty sets that is a simple integer where if someone gets in the train it increases with one and decreases by one else where, to know the number of empty seats at a given station A you  can do
number_of_empty_seats=total_number_of_seats-(number_of_itinerary_that_end_by_A + number_of_itinerary_that_end_BEFOR_A).

Comment: What I meant by 'time' is... if a client calls me and asks "I want to go from station C to station E, is there a seat available for me?". Otherwise, you're right, the concept of time doesn't really have any bearing on this problem. Also, your approach doesn't really address my problem since I'm not interested to know if there's a seat at the station (though that's important). What I want to know is "will there be a seat all the way through".

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudo code looks fine, although the step "count reservations" would need to be expanded in more detailed code as it would involve a loop.

You can improve a bit, by counting those reservations incrementally *as you loop* through the stations, so combining that counting with also tracking the minimum number of seats available. In order to incrementally update the number of free seats, you would first store the *changes* to the number of free seats at each station (+1 or -1 for each trip).

For large inputs, you would probably have to look into interval trees, but given that the numbers involved in your scenarios are tiny (in comments you mention numbers that are not greater than 10), that would be counter productive: the overhead of managing that interval tree would be more costly than what you gain.

So here is the proposed algorithm in a JavaScript implementation:

```js
function getNumFreeSeatsOnTrip(numSeats, trips, newTrip) {
    // Determine the number of seats that are free at each station
    const changeSeats = Array(newTrip.hopOff).fill(0);
    for (const trip of trips) {
        if (trip.hopOn < newTrip.hopOff) {
            changeSeats[trip.hopOn]--;
        }
        if (trip.hopOff < newTrip.hopOff) {
            changeSeats[trip.hopOff]++;
        }
    }
    // Determine the number of free seats at start of the new trip
    let seats = numSeats;
    for (let station = 0; station <= newTrip.hopOn; station++) {
        seats += changeSeats[station];
    }
    // Determine minimum of number of free seats during the new trip
    let minSeats = seats;
    for (let station = newTrip.hopOn + 1; station < newTrip.hopOff; station++) {
        seats += changeSeats[station];
        minSeats = Math.min(minSeats, seats);
    }
    return minSeats;
}

// Main:
const numSeats = 3;
const trips = [
    { hopOn: 0, hopOff: 2 }, // A-->C
    { hopOn: 0, hopOff: 1 }, // A-->B
    { hopOn: 0, hopOff: 4 }, // A-->E
    { hopOn: 1, hopOff: 3 }, // B-->D
];
const newTrip = { hopOn: 2, hopOff: 3 }; // C-->D
const freeSeats = getNumFreeSeatsOnTrip(numSeats, trips, newTrip);
console.log("free seats for trip from station 2 to 3:", freeSeats);
```

So the example here is depicted like this:

```
Station:     0     1     2     3     4
trip 1       on XxxxxxX off 
trip 2       on X off
trip 3       on XxxxxxXxxxxxXxxxxxX off
trip 4             on XxxxxxXxxxxxX off
-------------------------------------
free seats:     0     0     1     1
```

So in this example set up, no additional trip can start at stations 0 or 1 (A or B).